# Capacitor? Replacement with what value

Tags: capacitor

[image]

I have never seen this kind of component.

It looks like a resistor but the symbol and name says it is a capacitor.

Assuming it is a capacitor and the colour code brown black yellow the colour code website says the following result
100 nF ±2% (min:98, max:102 nF) 500V.

I want to replace it, please guide me what value capacitor should I replace it with

I have the following capacitor (image added.)

- 104K 630V
- 2A104J
- 104J 400V
- Disk type 104 AEC
- 104J200 PFV 0545

[image]

Comment: Why does it need replacing?

Comment: This is a pcb of top load washing machine, there is no power, and I have checked all the other components around the power switch they are working fine and this component in picture is short giving beep sound in multimeter.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this component is the issue.  You probably would also need to remove it from the board to test it, since there may be other components connected to it that are giving you a false reading on your meter.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please be aware, that questions concerning the repair of devices are considered off-topic here, because they are specific to the single device in most cases and won't bring benefit to the community.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a ceramic capacitor- the disk capacitor would be the closest replacement. The other types have more inductance so they are less suited for supply bypass.

Of course you can only check such capacitors **out of circuit**, which your photo suggests you may not have done.

The band looks more orange to me on this device which would mean 103 or 0.01uF/10nF. Perhaps there is another similar one on the board which you can compare.

On the other hand, if it’s a power supply bypass, then a 10:1 increase may not be an issue.